# Appending XML element to a STRING in SCALA

Tags: xml, scala, user-defined-functions

My input String looks like this

```
<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>

<p>This is my code:</p>

 <pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;
this.Opacity = trans;
</code></pre>

<p>When I build the application, it gives the following error:</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.</p>
</blockquote>

<p>I tried using <code>trans</code> and <code>double</code> but then the 
control doesn't work. This code worked fine in a past VB.NET project. </p>
,While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?
```

I am passing this string to a user-defined function in spark-scala. As you can see this string does not have a root element. So I am appending an XML element to this string.The function looks like this

```
case class bodyresults(text:String,code:String)

val bodyudf = udf{ (body: String)  =>


    //Appending body tag explicitly to the xml before parsing  
    val xmlElems = xml.XML.loadString(s"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE body [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]><body>${body}</body>""")
    // extract the code inside the req
    val code = (xmlElems \\ "body" \\ "pre" \\ "code").text

    val text = (xmlElems \\ "body").text.replace(s"${code}" ,"" )

    bodyresults(text, code)
}

val posts5 = posts4.withColumn("codetext", bodyudf($"Body") )
```

When I executed this I am getting this error

```
Error: The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</body>"
```

As you can see I am appending the closing tag . I am not able to find whats causing the error.

Can Anyone Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change `{$body}` to `${body}`

Comment: Actually, I am using ${body}  not {$body} . I edited the typo mistake in the post. Thanks